# Fragment can't handle many edittext

Tags: android

My app is crashing due to getting multiple edittext value
Here's my code

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextFullnames;
    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextUsername;

    public RegisterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textInputEditTextFullnames = container.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        textInputEditTextUsername = container.findViewById(R.id.username);
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    }
}
```

but it works if only one edittext

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextFullnames;

    public RegisterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textInputEditTextFullnames = container.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    }
}
```

it doesn't crash my app if only 1 edittext.

Can someone point out what i am doing wrong please

EDIT:

> 020-10-22 00:38:00.378 14272-14272/com.example.delmoverdriverapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.delmoverdriverapp, PID: 14272
> java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
> at com.example.delmoverdriverapp.RegisterFragment.onCreateView(RegisterFragment.java:39)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)

line 39 is the second `textInputEDitTextUsername`

Comment: Share your error

Comment: @FreddyDaniel I edited my question sir

Comment: Try to inflate your fragment of this way: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, null);` after this line add `yourEditText= view.findViewById(R.id.fullname1); yourEditText2= view.findViewById(R.id.fullname2);` then return the view  `return view`;

Comment: it gives me this ` 2020-10-22 00:45:59.312 14369-14369/com.example.delmoverdriverapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.delmoverdriverapp, PID: 14369
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        at com.example.delmoverdriverapp.RegisterFragment.onCreateView(RegisterFragment.java:39)`

Comment: Can you share with fragment_register.xml file?

Comment: Check the answer of @Yeldar.N it appear that you should use  AppCompatEditText for some input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and import `AppCompatEditText`:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextFullnames;
    AppCompatEditText textInputEditTextUsername;

    public RegisterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textInputEditTextFullnames = container.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        textInputEditTextUsername = container.findViewById(R.id.username);
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `fragment_register.xml` file exist several type of `EditText`. First is **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**, and second is **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText**. They have different parent classes, and when findViewById returns a `AppCompatEditText`  and try to cast into `TextInputEditText` it throws **java.lang.ClassCastException**.

Comment: can i use the button also for onclicklistener inside a fragment? last question

Comment: it's throwing me a null object i guess it couldn''t find the ID

Comment: Yes. Also I recommend to move initializations of views into `onViewCreated` method and there you can set all listeners.